# Springboot chaos-monkey assaults [memoryActive] not working

Tags: spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am using Springboot 2.3.1.RELEASE and chaos monkey its working fine for latencyActive ,exceptionsActive and CPU assault.

However, for memory assault, it's not working or I am not able to see memory usage reaches to my targetFraction.

** assault**

```
            "memoryActive": true,
            "memoryMillisecondsHoldFilledMemory": 90000,
            "memoryMillisecondsWaitNextIncrease": 500,
            "memoryFillIncrementFraction": 0.2,
            "memoryFillTargetFraction": 0.95,
            "memoryCronExpression": "0 41 10 ? * *"
```

I enabled the memory indicator in intellij to check the memory usage. also I change the maximum memory to 5000m. I can see the memory usage increase at real time, but it won't reach to 95%[memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8v9T.png)

I am expecting to see the memory usage reach to 95% and hold for 90s.